# How to extract value in between values using c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to extract some text in between and after some string.

The text is always different but the string to use by **indexOf**  method is always same
Here is how the string Data looks Like.

```
4D534D3839373400000000000000000001000000
61705F6B6C6F672E6C737400000000000800E0AF0700F0AF01000000
73756D6D6172792E68746D6C000000000000C0AFFFFFD7AF01000000
703166316532336535652E68746D6C000000C0AFFFFFD7AF01000000
703266316532336535652E68746D6C000000C0AFFFFFD7AF01000000
6472616D2E6C7374000000000000000000000080FFFFFFBF01000000
6F63696D656D2E6C737400000000000000006008FF3F600801000000
72706D5F636F64652E6C73740000000000002000FFFF210001000000
72706D5F646174612E6C73740000000000002900FFFF290001000000
72706D5F6D73672E6C737400000000000800F8AF0750F8AF01000000
646174612E7374617200645BC07B718F11000000E01117
```

This value is always constant: **01000000**

this is how it looks like when extracted:

```
4D534D38393734000000000000000000
61705F6B6C6F672E6C737400000000000800E0AF0700F0AF
73756D6D6172792E68746D6C000000000000C0AFFFFFD7AF
703166316532336535652E68746D6C000000C0AFFFFFD7AF
703266316532336535652E68746D6C000000C0AFFFFFD7AF
6472616D2E6C7374000000000000000000000080FFFFFFBF
6F63696D656D2E6C737400000000000000006008FF3F6008
72706D5F636F64652E6C73740000000000002000FFFF2100
72706D5F646174612E6C73740000000000002900FFFF2900
72706D5F6D73672E6C737400000000000800F8AF0750F8AF
646174612E7374617200645BC07B718F11000000E01117
```

And this is what I have tried so far I tried extracting indexes of all:  **01000000**
using this method:

```
public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
            for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length)
            {
                index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
                if (index == -1)
                    return indexes;
                indexes.Add(index);
            }
        }
```

How can I loop through all indexes and get the desired data.

Thanks

Comment: So your output is just a list of 11 strings?

Comment: @DavidG Nope always different.

Comment: Obviously, but you're just splitting the string on the `01000000` value every time?

Comment: the data is somehow formated using **bigEndian**

Comment: Yeah! the split function would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do this manually using `IndexOf`, you can simply split the string based on the string:

```
var s = "4D534D3.....";
var results = s.Split(new[] {"01000000"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Interesting that someone downvoted this, any reason why?